# Sumar resultados de una consulta

Tags: mysql, sum

he realizado una consulta a las tablas en sql que me arroja el último registro, pero aún me falta realizar la suma total de los precios que me arroja la consulta.
por favor si me pueden ayudar con eso.

la consulta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM deporte 
INNER JOIN precios on deporte.producto = precios.producto 
where fecha = (select max(fecha) from deporte )
```

[image: ese es el resultado que me arroja, pero no puedo hacer que sume]

Comment: pues en vez de traer * puedes traer sum(tot)

Comment: ¿Nos muestras que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí necesitas que se te muestren todos los campos y además la suma total de los precios.

```
select *, (select  Sum(precio) 
from deporte    
inner join precios on deporte.producto = precios.producto 
where fecha  = (select max(fecha) from deporte)) as total 
from deporte inner join precios 
on deporte.producto = precios.producto  
where fecha = (select max(fecha) 
from deporte;
```

Bien aquí lo que se hace es seleccionar todos los campos y además en la misma cláusula select se inserta una consulta la cual devuelve la suma total de los precios, a esta columna se le da como alias el nombre total, importante este select dentro del mismo select original debe devolver solo un campo.
Posteriormente ya en la parte del from de la consulta original se extraen los datos de las fechas recientes como bien tu planteas. Como verás los dos select son casi idénticos lo que uno devuelve todos los campos y el otro solamente devuelve la suma de todos los precios